i couldnt yarn start the project and i get this error
./src/bootstrap.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/bootstrap.scss)
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (115)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

please i need solotuion
i expect to run the app to localhost and still give me an error


Uninstall node-sass (it's reached end of life with e.g. yarn remove node-sass or npm remove node-sass
Install sass (aka. Dart Sass) instead, e.g. yarn add --dev sass.


Seems to me that you did not install sass package. So, you have to install it. If it doesn't work after installing, you have to install node-sass as well.
yarn add sass
or
yarn add node-sass

Installing both sass and node-sass is not a good idea.

Yes, I know that. This is why I already mentioned he has to install either node-sass or sass.

Your post is directing them to install both.
